# Any thoughts on a script to auto repair any failed table optimizes?

Tags: mysql

We've recently had a bit of a sticky situation - where after a power outage, the onsite engineers powered up a mysql database which hadn't flushed tables after the building's power was shut down.

We have two tables which reliably pass all sanity checks - but we have one that will successfully dump, and the other which can't be read from.

I was hoping to write either a somewhat sensible procedure, or else write a script to handle it when it happens again

Last time around it was a power outage in which the building was evacuated and the generators ran out of diesel, so we can be fairly certain it's going to happen again.

Answer (score 0):

This combination seems to give me the best results, after checking that replication has been successfully halted.

```
mysqlcheck  -P%PORT% -u%USER% %DB% --analyze --extended -vvv
mysqlcheck  -P%PORT% -u%USER% %DB% --auto-repair -g -vvv
mysqlcheck  -P%PORT% -u%USER% %DB% --auto-repair -vvv
mysqlcheck  -P%PORT% -u%USER% %DB% --optimize -vvv
```

Comment: Somewhat typically, writing the question, got me pointed in something of the right direction - but I'd be really interested in seeing what others have to suggest.